# In SQLite I am try to count people by current age when I have a column of birth dates

Tags: sql, sqlite

In SQLite I am try to count people by current age when I have a column of birth dates

e.g

> AGE: ------------------ COUNT:
>
> 17 ------------------------- 4
>
> 18 ------------------------- 7
>
> 19 ------------------------- 6
>
> etc......

Many Thanks,

Z

Comment: How often are you going to ask almost the same question about that topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select age,count(age) FROM
(select strftime('%Y',Date('now')) - strftime('%Y',birth) age
from table1)t
group by age;
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/3ade9/1)**